# Choosing last item with XSL

Tags: xslt

I am trying to edit an outgoing email that uses the block of code below to list all of the shipments in an order. However, it selects all of the shipments and we only want the last one.  Any ideas?  I know nothing of xsl so this is all foreign to me.

```
<xsl:variable name="order" select="//Order[1]" />
<xsl:variable name="address" select="$order/Address[@type='bill']" />
<xsl:value-of select="$address/FirstName" />

<p>Thank you for your order # <xsl:value-of select="$order/Number" />.
Your tracking information is available:
</p>

<p>
<xsl:if test="count($order//Shipment[IsProcessed = 'true' and (not(.//Voided) or .//Voided != 'true')]) = 0">
<i>(No shipments)</i>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:for-each select="$order//Shipment[IsProcessed = 'true' and (not(.//Voided) or .//Voided != 'true') ]">

      Shipped on <b><xsl:value-of select="sw:ToShortDate(ShippedDate)" /></b>
      using <b><xsl:value-of select="ServiceUsed" /></b>: <b><xsl:call-template name="outputTrackingLink" /></b>
     <br></br>
   </xsl:for-each>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">
  Shipped ...
</xsl:if>
```

around the printable part. Only the last item gets printed.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing it wrong initially and surrounding each "select" statement instead of just once.